# UI formatting with Thymeleaf and Spring MVC

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, formatting, thymeleaf

I need to format values in the UI in different ways:

No decimals: 15
One decimal: 15.4
Two decimals: 15.44
Percentage no decimals: 15%
Percentage one decimal: 15.4%
Percentage two decimals: 15:44%

What is the recommended way to achieve this? To use Thymeleaf numbers formatter to format to integer or decimal (and add % sign myself if needed). Or should I configure one or more Spring formatters with different formatting patterns?

Answer (score 0):

If you only show the value at one page I would format it in the template. If it's a form field or you need it on different pages I would use the [converter/formatter-approach of spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/previews/ui-format.html).

Comment: I ran into the same question as per_jansson and want to do this for different pages. So i wonder whats meant by "converter/formatter-approach of spring"?

Comment: @MarioEis follow the link in the answer.